# How to display information from processes which are running in session 0?

Tags: c, windows, software-distribution

For those who don't know what SCCM is, a little information, to understand better what i want to know. SCCM is an application, with you can deploy software packages. It is also possible to create a so called "Task Sequence". A Task sequence can contain multiple packages, which will be installed one after the other.

The Task Sequence execution occurs in Session 0. Of course the packages query some processes, if they are running. If they are, a window will pop up, to ask the user to close the application.

Here comes the problem. If an administrator deploys packages using task sequences (and they do), the users won't see the window, and won't close the required process. If the process is not closed, the script execution aborts.

I found this [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cameronk/archive/2010/04/27/creating-a-user-interactive-task-sequence-experience.aspx), and created a simple exe, according to the description. This simple exe is able to start a process from session 0 in session 1(or above), where the user is logged on(i know the security risks). So far so good, but how do i get the packages to display their windows? Obviously i could change the command line, so my exe will start the installation of every package, but this is not an option. There would be to much work.

The ideal solution would be if my exe would be the first in the task sequence, it would do "something" so the windows could be visible.

And that's where i am stuck.

Does anyone has any idea how i could achieve what i want?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: SCCM packages are supposed to be non-interactive, unless I'm very much mistaken.  However, if the Interactive Services Detection service is running it might detect your windows and prompt the user about it - although I think that depends on how the SCCM service is configured.  So try starting UI0Detect at the beginning of the task sequence and see if that helps.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, they supposed to be non-interactive. You are right. But in some cases, it is necessary to interact with the user. Thanks for the idea, i will try it, and report back, what results i got.

Comment: Have you checked whether it is possible to configure SCCM to run in the user's session?

Comment: It is not possible. If the interaction is allowed at the package properties, you can't even choose the package when creating the task sequence. Interaction must be disabled.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I tried to start UI0Detect but unfortunately nothing happened. It's the same. No window appear.